# ActiveMQ - override default CharacterSet

Tags: java, utf-8, activemq-classic, character-set

Is there a way to override the default CharacterSet and explicitly set it as UTF-8 in the ActiveMQ config (xml) or through a startup parameter?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Why do you want to override the default character set?